# Invalid use of the keyword Token 'message'

Tags: delphi, informix

I get this issue in delphi when I am trying to us tQuery and my query is

```
   SELECT membership_number, message_id, message, target, date_time_creation,
   date_time_display
   FROM MessageMembership
   WHERE membership_number = :membershipnumber    
   ORDER BY date_time_display desc;
```

I am using following code:

```
MessageMembershipSelectQuery.ParamByName('membershipnumber').AsString := 
custQuery.FieldByName('cust_code').AsString;
  MessageMembershipSelectQuery.Open;
```

Let me know what can be done to resolve this

Comment: TQuery - that's the BDE! I don't know what version of Delphi you're using, but **the BDE has been deprecated for years**. It sounds as if you're quite new to Delphi Db programming, so I suggest you switch to using dbExpress, ADO (or FireDac in recent versions), now that you don't have a large codebase yet. But stop using the BDE, it's too old, you'll get Unicode troubles etc.

Comment: The code that you are showing is not enough to go on. On what statement do you get the error message? Is MessageMembershipSelectQuery the specific TQuery you are talking about? As I write in my other comment the BDE is years ago that I touched it, but I can hardly imagine that **only** your query gives that error message. There must be something else going on.

Comment: I changed the column name from message to msgText and seems working though may be message is a reserved word in in informix. I am using informix as database backend. 
Can you suggest me how do I implement the dbNavigator based insert and update delete etc. because in my case they are not working what are the steps to implement the same? 
The data is displayed and insert button works but then the new row in the grid don't let me type enything in it?

Comment: Take a look here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.ejbbatchdeploy.doc%2Ftopics%2FrsqlINFORMIX_V94.html  and here:  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_1818.htm

Comment: Yes absolutely

The message was the keyword hence it was giving me error. 
I changed the column name and it worked

Comment: Write that in an answer to your question and accept it.

Comment: Have you tried to use `SELECT ... [message]`?

Comment: please take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions) and consider adding a good answer to your own question

Comment: @kobik: Transact-SQL is the only flavour of SQL that uses square brackets as name delimiters. The standard name delimiters in SQL are double quotes (`"message"`), and Informix seems to support them.